# from: can't read /var/mail/Adafruit_MotorHAT

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to hook up a motor controller to my raspberry pi 3b. I have followed this tutorial all the way to this page [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-dc-and-stepper-motor-hat-for-raspberry-pi/using-dc-motors).

On the first step of DC motor control walkthrough I get this screenshot of terminal:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: keep in mine that I am Extremely new at raspberry pi and coding so please speak to me in step by step answers and assume I know absolutley nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check, whether python is on you system:

```
edwards-iMac:~$ which -a python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

To enter live interpreter do this on your commandline:

```
python
```

Now you are in the shell (Live Interpreter).
Then you can enter the following line by line:

```
from Adafruit_MotorHAT import Adafruit_MotorHAT, Adafruit_DCMotor

import time
import atexit

mh = Adafruit_MotorHAT(addr=0x60)

def turnOffMotors():
    mh.getMotor(1).run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.RELEASE)
    mh.getMotor(2).run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.RELEASE)
    mh.getMotor(3).run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.RELEASE)
    mh.getMotor(4).run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.RELEASE)

atexit.register(turnOffMotors)
```

More here: http://pythoncentral.io/execute-python-script-file-shell/

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have pasted a script into your terminal. It's not going to work unless you invoke `python` first